# Is it possible to spy on an imported function within a Vue SFC using Vitest and Vue Test Utils?

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vue-test-utils, vitest

I'm working on unit testing all of my components, and I've hit a bit of a snag (or maybe a misunderstanding of how to properly test).

I have a component that receives some parameters from the store, and then calls a series of functions that mostly return an input string with some transformations applied.

This looks something like the following:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { someTextTransform } from '../utilities/someTextTransform';
...
let parsedText = store.input;

if (store.applySomeTextTransform) {
  parsedText = someTextTransform(parsedText);
}
```

I have already tested these functions themselves, so to me it seems like testing the actual output of the calls is unnecessary and I instead could just test to see if the functions have been called.

Here is a snippet on spying from the Vitest docs

> Mocking functions can be split up into two different categories; spying & mocking.

> Sometimes all you need is to validate whether or not a specific function has been called (and possibly which arguments were passed). In these cases a spy would be all we need which you can use directly with `vi.spyOn()`.

This is exactly what I want. I want only to know whether or not the function has been called. The functions themselves are simple enough that they do not require additional setup (i.e., mocking is not required).

However looking through the docs of Vue Test Utils I don't see a way to do this. It looks like a more common way to do this is to mock the functions first and then you can spy on them more easily, but then I would have to create mocks that don't actually mock the functions which seems like I'm adding code to my codebase for no benefit other than a weird workaround.

I may just be missing something on how to do this, but I might also be approaching the testing in a suboptimal way so any advice is appreciated.